# Named Entity joining and assigning to a variable

Tags: python-3.x

How is it possible to join named entities and assign to a variable

```
[[('Joel', 'PERSON'),
  ('Thompson', 'PERSON'),
  ('Tracy', 'PERSON'),
  ('K', 'PERSON'),
  ('Smith', 'PERSON'),
  ('New', 'ORGANIZATION'),
  ('Work', 'ORGANIZATION'),
  ('World', 'ORGANIZATION'),
  ('Premierenew', 'ORGANIZATION'),
  ('York', 'ORGANIZATION'),
  ('Philharmonic', 'ORGANIZATION'),
  ('Commission', 'ORGANIZATION')]]
```

**Desired Output**

```
PERSON : Joel Thompson Tracy K Smith
ORGANIZATION : New Work World Premierenew York Philharmonic Commission
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a combination of list comprehensions/generator expressions and [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> names = [('Joel', 'PERSON'), ... , ('Commission', 'ORGANIZATION')]
>>> [(k, " ".join(t[0] for t in v)) for k, v in groupby(names, key=lambda t: t[1])]
[('PERSON', 'Joel Thompson Tracy K Smith'),
 ('ORGANIZATION', 'New Work World Premierenew York Philharmonic Commission')]
```

or, if you prefer a `dict`:

```
>>> dict((k, " ".join(t[0] for t in v)) for k, v in groupby(names, key=lambda t: t[1]))
{'PERSON': 'Joel Thompson Tracy K Smith',
 'ORGANIZATION': 'New Work World Premierenew York Philharmonic Commission'}
```